# Getting Current Login Username in Acumatica [Generic Inquiry]

Tags: acumatica

Is it possible to get Current Login Username in Acumatica [Generic Inquiry] Screen? and be used as parameter value for conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using @me which could link up to pKID on the User Table.
We use 2017 R2 Acumatica and @me proving to be problematic.
Also avoid tying to use AccessInfo in your GI as that also does not work yet.

I hope this points you into some direction.